# Linear projection operator

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Prove that linear operator from $V$ to itself with property $\rho = \rho^2$ is a projection operator.
It is just a standard result on textbook,what I don't understand is why the proof on the textbook first prove that $V$ is direct sum of $\ker \rho$ and $Img\ \rho$?
By the property of $\rho = \rho^2$ .

Since $V$ is direct sum of $\ker \rho$ and $Img\ \rho$ is just a general result for linear transformation,why we need to show this result again by idempotent?

Comment: Are you saying that, for every linear map $\rho\colon V\longrightarrow V$, we have $V=\ker\rho\bigoplus\operatorname{Im}\rho$?

Comment: Yes? Do I  misinterpret it?

Comment: It's not a general property of linear operators. While the dimensions of the kernel and the image of an arbitrary linear operator on $V$ sum to the dimension of $V$, these subspaces can have non-trivial intersections (and thus fail to sum to $V$, directly or not). As an example, consider any nilpotent operator.

Comment: You are wrong then. If $\rho\colon\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R^2$ is the map defined by $\rho(x,y)=(y,0)$, then $(1,0)\in\ker\rho\cap\operatorname{Im}\rho$.

Comment: Since image isomorphic to $V/Ker$, it does not mean image is exactly the complement,and if $V = \ker +Img$ then it's direct sum .am I right?

Comment: @yi_li What do you mean? The complement of a subspace is never subspace. What you've written is a quotient.

Comment: I mean image is not exactly the subspace expanded by the rest of the basis of $V$.Since complement does not have 0,hence it can't be a subspace,and also even if it has 0, we can shift  both vectors in $S$ by a vector in complement that a-b in subspace hence complement is not a subspace.

Comment: To show $V=\ker\rho\bigoplus\operatorname{Im}\rho$ we just need to show $V=\ker\rho + \operatorname{Im}\rho$ am I right?